# R system() call doesn't work when run from a for loop or lapply in a .Rmd R notebook

Tags: r, linux

I want to run a set of bash commands generated via this code chunk from a .Rmd Rnotebook. I would like to run the bash commands from the script using system(). For some reason this does not work when I run it in an R script but will work when I run it from the R commandline.

````
    ```{r, rmdSystemChuckThatDoesntWork}
    
    fooFiles <- paste0("echo foobar > foobarFile", 1:4, ".txt")
    
    #works from the console ... not sure why its being broken from the .Rmd
    lapply(fooFiles, system)
    
    #doesnt work in script but does in console
    foreach::foreach ( i = fooFiles) %do% {
      print(i)
      system(i)
    }
    
    #doestn work in script but does in console
    system(fooFiles[1])
    system(fooFiles[2])
    
    #slash is there for formatting code in this post to show where the ticks would land 
    the slash is not in the .Rmd code
    \```
````

The same thing copy and pasted into a regular .R script works just fine though

Also these same line of code run just fine in the R console.

```
    > version
                   _                           
    platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu         
    arch           x86_64                      
    os             linux-gnu                   
    system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
    status                                     
    major          3                           
    minor          6.1                         
    year           2019                        
    month          07                          
    day            05                          
    svn rev        76782                       
    language       R                           
    version.string R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
    nickname       Action of the Toes
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "doesn't work" in this case. Are you getting an error message of some sort? How are you calling your scripts or compiling your Rmd files? Are you using full file paths or relative file paths. Are you using the same working directory in all cases?

Comment: You could output `getwd()` in a chunck to see the directory used for knitting.